# Why is background color not changing for navbar on scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I want navbar to be transparent for during the image animation and have a black background when you scroll to text. The if condition doesn't seem to work.

HTML:

```
<nav id="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
.newNav{
    background: black;
}
```

JS:

```
let nav = document.getElementById("navbar"); 
window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
            let value = window.scrollY;
if(value>100){
                nav.classList.add("newNav");
            }
            else{
                nav.classList.remove("newNav");
            }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: you are missing a `)` at the end. It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/itgoldman/up6qw5ot/6/

Comment: There is no image in the code you have given so we can’t tell what switches its animation on or off. Also, once the user has scrolled 100 the bar will remain black.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
  nav {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: 0.5s;
    }
```

JS:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = "black";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.background = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).